# How properly apply composition in Test Automation using Java and POM design pattern?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, playwright

Could someone please share best practices for applying the composition in UI test automation using Java

If I have multiple Pages that can open a component Modal I could probably implement fields and actions inside of each class:

```
class PageA {
  private static final String CHECKBOX_ON_MODAL = "//div[@id='checkbox']"

  public selectCheckBox() {
    //implementation of select method here
  }
}
```

```
class PageB {
  private static final String CHECKBOX_ON_MODAL = "//div[@id='checkbox']";

  public selectCheckBox() {
    //implementation of select method here
  }
}
```

```
class PageC {
  private static final String CHECKBOX_ON_MODAL = "//div[@id='checkbox']"

  public selectCheckBox() {
    //implementation of select method here
  }
}
```

so now using composition I can create a class of Modal to make this component reusbale across multiple pages:

```
class Modal {
  private static final String CHECKBOX_ON_MODAL = "//div[@id='checkbox']";

  public selectCheckBox() {
    //implementation of select method here
  }
}
```

and add it to my pages:

```
class PageA {
  private Modal modal;

  public PageA() {
    modal = new Modal();
  }

  public Modal getModal() {
    return modal;
  }
}

class PageB {
  private Modal modal;

  public PageB() {
    modal = new Modal();
  }

  public Modal getModal() {
    return modal;
  }
}

class PageC {
  private Modal modal;

  public PageC() {
    modal = new Modal();
  }

  public Modal getModal() {
    return modal;
  }
}
```

and in my tests use like this:

```
public final class TestExample {

@Test
public void test1 () {
PageA pageA = new PageA();
Modal modal = pageA.getModal();

modal.selectCheckBox();
    }

@Test
public void test2 () {
PageB pageB = new PageB();
Modal modal2 = pageB.getModal();

modal2.selectCheckBox();
    }

@Test
public void test3 () {
PageC pageC= new PageC();
Modal modal3 = pageC.getModal();

modal3.selectCheckBox();
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that - when the behaviour/state/visibility of the checkbox i different and depends on the the page from which the modal was opened. For example on Page A the checkbox on the Modal is visible and active, on Page B the checkbox is visible but greyed out, on Page C the checkbox is not even visible etc.

How do I restrict actions to interract with the object at compile time depending on the Page I'm opening the modal?

The answers that I got already are:

- Implement the actions to interract with the checkbox in the Page classes - but in this case I'm not sure I'm getting the point of composition.
- Create an interface and implement it as a Modal classes for different pages - but in this case I can just create different classes for the modal without an interface, even I can just add fields and actions for the modal and its' objects to the respective Page classes
- Pass some checkers as arguments to test methods - kinda makes implementation not clean.

So, I would like to hear what are your thoughs on how to solve this in simple and efficient way.
Thank you

Implement the actions to interract with the checkbox in the Page classes - but in this case I'm not sure I'm getting the point of composition.

Create an interface and implement it as a Modal classes for different pages - but in this case I can just create different classes for the modal without an interface

Pass some checkers as arguments to test methods - kinda makes implementation not clean.

Comment: Maybe extend a class and override the method(s) when/if necessary?

Comment: what would be the point of overriding selectChecbox method if I just don't want this method to be available for modal object called from the page where this checkbox is not visible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Max, how about ensuring that the checkbox is visible and active and then making a click on it. What do you do if the checkbox is not visible? Accordingly, you may either have a separate method for this verification and then do action. Or in the selectCheckbox() method itself, you can have a check and return true/false or exception accordingly.

Comment: thank you @AhamedAbdulRahman, I was thinking about this approach and it might work.
But I was thinking if there is a capability in java to restrict method calls based on the object it is called from.
For example:

`//Checkbox is visible
pageA.getModal().selectCheckBox();`

`//Checkbox is not visible
pageB.getModal().selectCheckBox(); // compile error because the method is not available`